# How to apply datatable dynamically in nested form OR how to integrate datatable with nested forms?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datatables, nested-forms

Order have `has_many` association with item while item have also `has_many` association with `records`

I use `gem nested_form` to add records. I use `datatable` form for records.

```
<table cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px" border="0" class="table-inn table-striped myTable">
    <%= item.fields_for :records do |record| %>
      <thead class="panel-heading">
        //
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          //
        </th>
      </tbody>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

For first item `datatable` works. but when I click on `<%= f.link_to_add "Add More Item", :items %>` It not load `datatable`

```
$('.myTable').dataTable();
```

What I do that datable load dyanamically?